# Naming the jpg files in a loop

Tags: r, loops, naming

I am doing a loop operation which reads from the same column of two dataframes (obs & sim)and produces scatter plots.  . There are 24 columns in total in each data frame. The following script works fine.

```
for(i in 1:24) {
  plot (obs[,i],sim[,i],xlab="obs",ylab="sim",main=substitute(paste('Lead Time (hrs) = ', a), list(a=i)))
}
```

But I want to save each and every plots in a folder (C:/RPlots/)  and I want to include this operation also in the loop.

I used the following script , but it didn't work

```
for(i in 1:24) {
  jpeg('C:/RPlots/paste("myplot_", c(i), ".jpg")')
  plot (obs[,i],sim[,i],xlab="obs",ylab="sim",main=substitute(paste('Lead Time (hrs) = ', a), list(a=i)))
  dev.off()
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you got an error in `jpeg` call

try this

```
for(i in 1:24) {
jpeg(paste0("C:/RPlots/myplot_",i,".jpg")) 
plot (obs[,i],sim[,i],xlab="obs",ylab = "sim",
      main = substitute(paste('Lead Time (hrs) = ', a), list(a = i))) 
dev.off() 
}
```

Comment: `paste0` combines string without a paste.
Also, I would suggest PNG with a resolution of 300, read `?png` for details

Comment: Thank you,infominer. That works fine. thanks for the additional info too. But I need to get all plots in .jpg format for a special purpose. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `paste`, `paste0`, or `sprintf` to create the names, but it is simpler to just use an integer format in the file argument.

For example if you start the jpeg device with a command like:

```
jpeg('C:/RPlots/myplot_%03d.jpg')
```

before the loop, then create multiple plots in the loop, then the first plot will be saved in file myplot_001.jpg, the second in myplot_002.jpg, the third in myplot_003.jpg, etc.

The "%03d" is the important part, the 3 means you want 3 digit numbers and the 0 means pad them with a 0.  Adjust for your preferences.

Comment: I like this answer for the reason it used the built-in counter. could you please edit it (remove the one and add a quote). looks like you were quick on the trigger :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Greg Snow, if you cannot place the `jpeg()` function outside of the loop for whatever reason, there is `sprintf()` of C library fame:

```
paste0("C:/RPlots/myplot",sprintf("%03d",i),".jpg")
```

Here, `i` is an integer from a for loop iterator. This sets the leading zero padding, which is nice if you want to later iterate over these images with `ffmpeg`, etc.